# Install a package from private registry using yarn

Tags: github, npm, npm-install, yarn-v2

I am trying to install a private package from the GitHub registry. It works fine with npm but throws a 401 (Unauthorized) when I use yarn to install the same package. I have used .npmrc file for configuring the repository and below is the content of the file,

```
@Qualifier:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=GITHUB_TOKEN
```

GITHUB_TOKEN is a PAT (personal access token) generated in GITHUB. The same token is used while creating the package using GitHub actions as below,

```
env:
  NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for you is to [update yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration) to 2.x> version (if it isn't updated yet) and configure your `.yarnrc.yml` following [this docs](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc)

It should look something like this

```
 npmScopes:
  "your-registry":
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmRegistryServer: "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
    npmAuthToken: "githubTokenHere"
```